# Wirecloud couldn't open settings of widget

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I got a instance of wirecloud, I've added there a few widgets, but I couldn't open the settings of the widget in one of them. I've tested the widgets in the fiware instance of wirecloud, there they worked very good.
The problem is that I could click on settings, but it didn't open a settings window.

I noticed that the instance of the fiware seems to be more friendly, I hat to edit the config.xml a few times before my own instance accepted it.

Does somebody know where the problem could be?

EDIT:
After a lot of trial&error I am able to set the settings in the Django-managemenet. So, it seems to be that the options are recognized, but not shown. Do I need to enable them?

Answer (score 0):

Problem got solved by installing wirecloud from the develop branch after commit a6f4125f82 .